# Search query using .Contains() for parameters that combine two columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got a table with FirstName and LastName and a query that looks somewhat like this:

```
var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
                where (c.FirstName.Contains(TheSearchParameter)  ||
                       c.LastName.Contains(TheSearchParameter))
                select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

If a user searches for John or for Smith, there'll be records returned but if the user searches for John Smith, no records come back. How does `Contains()` work and what would I need to change in my query for it to work as expected?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? You have given a single example which is not enough. Do you want to search for words in any of the two columns? If the user enters `Smith John` is this supposed to match anything?

Comment: @usr: at the moment, if the user enters "John Smith", there are no results. The first name and last name are in two different columns and the expected result would be that the record where John is the first name and Smith the last name be included in the search result.

Comment: So are you matching words? Split the query into words first. Would that work?

Comment: Spliting John Smith would mean that John Adams would come up too but that's a good direction.

Comment: Please specify what behavior exactly you want! For example, what happens when the user searches for "a b c"? What would that match. You are wasting time and your bounty right now because nobody knows what you want. Also, you are not exhaustively answering my comments which is wasting further time.

Comment: @usr: the problem seems pretty clear. In general terms, if a user search for text that spawn over several rows of the same record then that record should be returned. But you're right, if a user search for "a b" and there's an "a" and a "b" in two different columns then that becomes problematic. In my case, I require the search term to be 3 characters long. What do you recommend?

Comment: @usr: yes, still VERY interested; just working on another part of the code but I'll be back to it soon.

Comment: You need to respond to all answers and do it before the bounty expires.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than start playing with combinations of `and`, `or`, `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` etc., let analyze the main issue:

> Search query using `.Contains()` for parameters that **combine two columns**

So the general answer is:

```
where Combine(table.Column1, table.Column2).Contains(TheSearchParameter)
```

The question is though what is the `Combine` function, and there is no general answer to that.

In your particular case, looks like you want to search for a `Name` which is combination of `FirstName` and `LastName` columns.

Even that combination is not generally defined (different languages have different name rules), but assuming you have in mind the most common name combinator:

```
Name = "{FirstName} {LastName}"
```

then the query is simply

```
var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
                where (c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName).Contains(TheSearchParameter)
                select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

For instance, if there is a **Contact** with **FirstName**: *"John"*, **LastName**:*"Smith"*, the above query will match *"John"*, *"Smith"*, *"John Smith"* but not *"Smith John"*.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adding `StartsWith` method in your LINQ expression. StartsWith works similar to SQL `where Column LIKE 'Something%'`. You might add `EndsWith` also to make your search more wide

```
var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
                where (c.FirstName.Contains(TheSearchParameter)  ||
                       c.FirstName.StartsWith(TheSearchParameter) ||
                       c.FirstName.EndsWith(TheSearchParameter) ||
                       c.LastName.StartsWith(TheSearchParameter) ||
                       c.LastName.EndsWith(TheSearchParameter) ||
                       c.LastName.Contains(TheSearchParameter))
                select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

```
var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
            where ((c.FirstName.Contains(TheSearchParameter) && 
                    c.LastName.Contains(TheSearchParameter)) ||
                   (c.FirstName.Contains(TheSearchParameter) ||
                    c.LastName.Contains(TheSearchParameter)))
            select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Using `( condition && condition ) ||` Will force the internals of the brackets to be a single expression while leaving the existing conditions in place.

Let me know if not. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

It is my current understanding that you want to search for words across columns. While I'm sure I do not yet fully understand the requirements I want to contribute the following idea. Hopefully, you'll be able to make it into a full solution:

```
var words = searchQuery.Split(' ');
var query = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
             select c);

//Force each word to occur.
foreach (var w in words)
 query = query.Where(c => c.FN.Contains(w) || c.LN.Contains(w));

var TheQuery = (from c in query
                select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

This introduces the concept of searching for all words as opposed to searching for only one string.

If you want separate logic for first name and last name you could have two lists of words: One for FN and one for LN.

Answer (score 1):

I think everybody making the simple thing complex. The main intension is to get the resultant Contact which matches the given Name. There are two scenarios,
1. You need to find the exact match. Use the following query,

```
    var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
                    where (TheSearchParameter.Split(' ').Any(s => c.FirstName.Contains(s)) ||
                    TheSearchParameter.Split(' ').Any(s => c.LastName.Contains(s)))
                    select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

2. You need find all the related matches

   ```
   var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
         where (c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName == TheSearchParameter)
         select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (I prefer to use lambdas, but you don't have to):

```
var results = MyDC.Contacts
  .Where(c => string.Join(" ",c.FirstName,c.LastName).Contains(TheSearchParameter))
  .Select(c => c.ColumnId)
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();
```

By combining FirstName and LastName into a single string, you save yourself several comparisons.

**Edit**: Updated the formatting since it was kind of hard to follow on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

> How does `Contains` work

Assuming your `FirstName` and `LastName` are of `string` type, `Contains` will check if any of the substring of the string matches with your `TheSearchParameter`

Thus, `c.FirstName.Contains("John")` will match if the `c.FirstName` is any of the following:

```
John
vbJohn
John123
vbJohn123
```

It is case sensitive though, thus the following won't match:

```
john
vbjohn
john123
vbjohn123
```

> what would I need to change in my query for it to work as expected

Assuming if you have the following name list:

```
John Bryant
John Bard
Smith Bard
John Smith
Ralla Smith
Smith John
Metajohn Rasmith
```

And I assume the most natural "search" that you probably want, that is,

1. the more items you add as the key word, the less items you should get ("John" `TheSearchParameter` should return more results than "John Smith").
2. The order doesn't matter.
3. Exact matching required (since you deal with name)

Thus, by putting "John" you want to return:

```
John Bryant
John Bard
John Smith
Smith John
```

And by putting "Smith"

```
Smith Bard
John Smith
Ralla Smith
Smith John
```

While putting "John Smith"

```
John Smith
Smith John
```

What I suggest you to do is by making it **case insensitive** and checking it like this:

```
string TheSearchParameter = "John Smith";
TheSearchParameter = TheSearchParameter.ToLower(); //case insensitive
string[] pars = TheSearchParameter.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //to get all the pars
var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
                let l = new List<string>() {c.FirstName.ToLower(), c.LastName.ToLower()}
                where l.Except(pars).Count() <= l.Count - pars.Length
                select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

The key here is the

```
where l.Except(pars).Count() <= l.Count - pars.Length
```

By which you control the number of matches that you want to consider as true matching. The more words you use in `SearchParameter`, the less amount of `l.Except` which you expected to have (because more words in the name have to match in the search parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Good day, please consider my approach

both answers above will not return if searching for full name because they searched exclusively with FirstName and LastName

(ex:

```
John.Contains(John Smith) = false

Smith.Contains(John Smith) = false

John.StartsWith(John Smith) = false

Smith.StartsWith(John Smith) = false

John.EndsWith(John Smith) = false

Smith.EndsWith(John Smith) = false

)

    var TheQuery = (from c in x where ((TheSearchParameter.Contains(c.FirstName)
                                     && TheSearchParameter.Contains(c.LastName)) ||
                   ((c.FirstName.Contains(TheSearchParameter) || 
                     c.LastName.Contains(TheSearchParameter)))) 
                   select c.ColumnId).Distinct().ToList();
```

The First Part where the `TheSearchParameter.Contains(c.First/LastName)` will consider searching for `TheSearchParameter` with parts of the first AND last name

The Second Part Will Consider the searching for First OR Last Name with `TheSearchParameter`

if you search "John Smith"

and have John Smith, John Paul and Paul Smith records

The First part will return 1 result: John Smith
The Second Part will return 0

if you search "John"

The First part will return 0 result
The Second Part will return: John Smith and John Paul

if you search "Smith"

The First Part will return 0
The Second Part will return: John Smith and Paul Smith

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Let's assume that the Collection contains a record with FirstName as `John` and LastName as `Smith` and There is another record with FirstName='Sam' and LastName as 'SmithX'. And The `TheSearchParameter` will contains the word to search.

**Now Let's examine How your query will work up on different inputs.**

**Case 1 :** *TheSearchParameter= 'John'* - Will give you the expected result since `c.FirstName.Contains(TheSearchParameter)` evaluates to `true`

**Case 2 :** *TheSearchParameter= 'Smith'* - Will give you the expected result since `c.LastName.Contains(TheSearchParameter)` evaluates to `true`

**Case 3 :** *TheSearchParameter= 'Jo'*Will give you the expected result since `c.FirstName.Contains(TheSearchParameter)` evaluates to `true`

Upto this everything is fine; Now

**Case 4 :** *TheSearchParameter= 'John Smith'* - Will give you Empty result set Since there is no FirstName or LastName that Contains `John Smith` But it is a combination of both.

What you can do to get the correct result in all these cases:

Since the `TheSearchParameter` may include firstName or LastName or Both, Perform the search operation in `TheSearchParameter`. So your Query May Looks like:

```
var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
                where (TheSearchParameter.Contains(c.FirstName)  ||
                       TheSearchParameter.Contains(c.LastName))
                select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now, It Gives the same result for *Case 1-3* And Will Give Two Records("John Smith" and "Sam Smith" Even though the last name is Different. since `TheSearchParameter.Contains(c.LastName)` Is evaluates to true; Now We have to Sort-out this;

So the fact is that

If the input is Combination of FirstName and LastName We have To Confirm that The combination Should Start with `FirstName` and EndsWith `LastName`. So I Suggest you to Use such a Searching mechanism. The following snippet will Help you to do that;

```
  var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
                  where ((TheSearchParameter.Contains(c.FirstName) && TheSearchParameter.StartsWith(c.FirstName)) ||
                        (TheSearchParameter.Contains(c.LastName) && TheSearchParameter.EndsWith(c.FirstName)))
                 select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If we assume that the name is compose of first name and last name
   only, and you have no middle name in your data. User Full Name =
   First Name + Last Name. Maybe the follow code you can try:

   ```
   var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
               where (c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName).Contains(TheSearchParameter)
               select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
   ```
2. we check `FirstName` and `LastName` in `TheSearchParameter`:

   ```
   var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
               where (c.FirstName.Contains(TheSearchParameter) ||
                       c.LastName.Contains(TheSearchParameter) ||
                       TheSearchParameter.StartsWith(c.FirstName) ||
                       TheSearchParameter.EndsWith(c.LastName)
                       )
               select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
   ```

   e.g.: Jhon Smith `"Jhon Smith".StartsWith("Jhon")` or `"Jhon
   Smith".EndsWith("Smith")` is true when Jhon or Smith is in
   `Contacts`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] parametersArray = null;
        int parametersCount = 0;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TheSearchParameter))
        {
            parametersArray = TheSearchParameter.Split(new char[0],StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            parametersCount = parametersArray.Length;
        }

        var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
                        where (parametersCount == 0 || (parametersCount > 0 && (parametersArray.Contains(c.FirstName) ||
                               parametersArray.Contains(c.LastName))))
                        select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var TheQuery = (from c in MyDC.Contacts
                where (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(c.FirstName, TheSearchParameter, System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(c.Lastname, TheSearchParameter, System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0)
                       select c.ColumnID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not quite understand why are you expecting your statement to work.

```
string x =  "abc" ;
string y = "abc def";

y.Contains(x); // returns true
x.Contains(y); // returns false
```